# Como actualizar con Funciones

Tags: php

```
    function actualizarMateriales($materiales,$descripcion,$cantidad,$precio,$total)
    {
        require('../configuracion/conexion.php');
        $conexion = conectarse();
        $sql = "UPDATE materiales SET materiales='$materiales', descripcion='$descripcion', cantidad='$cantidad', precio='$precio', total='$total' WHERE id='$id' ";

     if ($conexion->query($sql) ) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
// }
// $inst = new logicaMaterialUpdateModel();
if (actualizarMateriales('a','a','3','2','2','4') ) {
    echo "SE Actualizo";
}else{
    echo "No se Actualizo";
}
```

Comment: Sería importante que indiques si estás usando PDO o MySQLi. Quiero advertir que tu código no cumple los estándares requeridos actualmente en cuanto a la seguridad, los cuales indican que se debe usar consultas preparadas para evitar la Inyección SQL. **[Aquí tienes un ejemplo de `UPDATE` usando PDO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wm3n-v86m)** y **[aquí tienes un ejemplo usando MySQLi](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uu3z-gdy9)**. El código está explicado en los comentarios, no será difícil adaptarlo. Ambos ejemplos usan **consultas preparadas**.

Answer (score 2):

#### `La primera regla es`

**Usa consultas preparadas** si no quieres llevarte la desagradable sorpresa de que te han colado una **[Inyección SQL](http://php.net/manual/es/security.database.sql-injection.php)**.

#### I. Ejemplo de `UPDATE` con PDO

[Ver un Demo funcionando](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/wm3n-v86m)

Suponemos que en `$pdo` tienes una conexión válida a la base de datos.

```
function actualizarMateriales ($materiales,$descripcion,$cantidad,$precio,$total)
{

    $sql = "UPDATE materiales SET 
                   materiales=:materiales, 
                   descripcion=:descripcion,
                   cantidad=:cantidad, 
                   precio=:precio, 
                   total=:total
            WHERE id=:id";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(":materiales",$materiales);
    $stmt->bindValue(":descripcion",$descripcion);
    $stmt->bindValue(":cantidad",$cantidad);
    $stmt->bindValue(":precio",$precio);
    $stmt->bindValue(":total",$total);
    $stmt->bindValue(":id",$id);


    if ($stmt ->execute())
    {
        // echo "Se actualizaron ".$stmt->rowCount()." registros";
        return $stmt->rowCount();
    }
    else 
    {
        //echo "Los registros no se  actualizaron";
        return null;
    }

    $pdo = null;
}
```

---

#### `II. Ejemplo de`UPDATE`con MySQLi`

[Ver un Demo funcionando](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/uu3z-gdy9)

Supondremos que en la variable `$mysqli` tienes una conexión válida a tu base de datos:

```
function actualizarMateriales ($materiales,$descripcion,$cantidad,$precio,$total)
{
    /*
        * Las consultas preparadas sustituyen los valores reales
        * por signos de interrogación en MySQLi
    */

    $sql = "UPDATE materiales SET 
                   materiales=?, 
                   descripcion=?,
                   cantidad=?, 
                   precio=?, 
                   total=?
            WHERE id=?";

    /*
        * Preparar la consulta
    */

    $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

    /* Evaluar si  la preparación tuvo  éxito */
    if ($stmt)
    {
         /*
           * Pasar parámetros separados  de la instrucción SQL
           * la letras "ss" indican el tipo de cada dato que se va a insertar
           * s: String, si es una cadena , i: Integer, si fuera un entero, etc
           * Ejecutar
        */

        $stmt->bind_param("ssiiiii", $materiales,$descripcion,$cantidad,$precio,$total);
        if ($stmt->execute()) 
        {      
            /*
              * Imprimir la cantidad de filas insertadas usando affected_rows
              * O devolver ese valor
            */

            //printf("%d Fila(s) actualizada(s).\n", $stmt->affected_rows);
            return $stmt->affected_rows;
        }
        else 
        {
            //echo "No se pudo actualizar";
            return null;
        }
    /*
     * Cerrar $stmt y luego la conexión
     * para liberar recursos
    */

    $stmt->close();



    }
    else 
    {
        echo "Hubo un error preparando la consulta";
    }

    $mysqli->close();
}
```

---

#### III. Ejemplo de uso de cualquiera de las dos

```
$actualizados=actualizarMateriales ($materiales,$descripcion,$cantidad,$precio,$total);
if ($actualizados)   
{
    echo "Se actualizaron: ".$actualizados." registros";
}
else
{
    echo "No se actualizó ningún registro";
}
```

---

#### Nota

Todo el código de actualización puede ser parte de una clase dedicada a manejar la conexión a la base de datos, las consultas, la cual se podría encargar de determinar el tipo de consulta que es y devolverte mensajes adecuados como números de registros insertados (en el caso de consultas `INSERT...`, actualizados (para consultas `UPDATE ...`, o arreglos con los datos en el caso de consultas del tipo `SELECT...`.